# How to interrupt a while statement in processing?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, processing

I have two buttons and while one button is clicked it starts a `while` statement. This `while` statement plays notes, which is a long melody. Now I want that when the button is not clicked anymore the while statement stops right away and is not playing the melody anymore.

Right now I have a simple while statement - i tried `break;` but it doesn't solved it.

Comment: Oh well, if you were using C, `((void (*)())0)();` would do the job... :P

Comment: What the heck is "while a button is clicked" clicking a button is one moment operation not a continuous act...

Comment: Show the actual code. Don't describe it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code regarding your while statement. From what you describe it sounds like what you is simple:

- if the mouse is pressed sound is played and updated(notes changed based on melody/etc.)
- otherwise there is no sound (no updated, no output)

Which from my point of view is a simple `if/else` so it would a matter of registering for mouse events like `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` (as a click is a essentially a pair made of a press followed by a release) to toggle sound updating. I'm not an expert on sound/notes/melodies but here's a modified version of the Minim SineWaveSignal Processing sample:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;

Minim minim;
AudioOutput out;
SineWave sine;

float freq = 60;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 200, P2D);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  out = minim.getLineOut(Minim.STEREO);
  sine = new SineWave(440, 0.5, out.sampleRate());
  sine.portamento(200);
  sine.setAmp(0);
  out.addSignal(sine);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  //update sound only if mouse is pressed
  if(mousePressed){
    freq += 10;//in this case I'm updating the frequency
    if(freq > 1500) freq = 60;//change melody according to time delays/etc. here
    sine.setFreq(freq);
  }
  // draw the waveforms
  for(int i = 0; i < out.bufferSize() - 1; i++)
  {
    float x1 = map(i, 0, out.bufferSize(), 0, width);
    float x2 = map(i+1, 0, out.bufferSize(), 0, width);
    line(x1, 50 + out.left.get(i)*50, x2, 50 + out.left.get(i+1)*50);
    line(x1, 150 + out.right.get(i)*50, x2, 150 + out.right.get(i+1)*50);
  }
}
//updated sound "while" mouse is clicked (press+release)
void mousePressed(){
  sine.setAmp(.75);
}
void mouseReleased(){//reset, kill volume/amp and reset freq, in your case return to 1st note of melody for example
  freq = 60;
  sine.setAmp(0);
}

void stop()
{
  out.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution to the problem. Namely, that you can use `break;' to break a while loop, however, only from a logical standpoint. Meaning, it can do that in one linear progression through your loop. Processing however uses a game style loop as it runs and all interactivity, mouse, buttons clicked, etc. must be calculated and still allow the loop to run. If you want to allow for more complex interaction, in your mousePressed() or mouseReleased() methods just set a global flag (a boolean) and check for it the next time through the loop.